# Help recovering data from /dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

About a year ago I had a micro SD 128Gb that had all my important documents and a bunch of really valuable pictures of my daughter.
One day I was transferring a folder that was 40Gb from my Samsung phone to the SD card to empty space on my phone but somehow while the transfer was being done the process crashed and my card got corrupted or something because now is unreadable, whenever I plugged into my phone it asks me to format it and whenever I plugged to my computer I get the error "/dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label" which for what I know it means either the partition table was corrupted or the disks label got corrupted as well.
Now, I know I can recover all my photos using "testdisk" but I have use that before and it was incredibly annoying because I ended up with about 1000 folders and there were not organise at all so I was wondering if there's a better way to recover my data, I also attempted to use gparted but their "attempt data rescue" has been scanning the SD card for about 4 hours with no results so I was wondering if anyone knows the commands to do it on the terminal if that´s even possible.

Comment: The easy options are to restore a copy from your backup.  If you don't have backups, then you fall back to the manual methods like `testdisk` etc.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 0):

On occasion, I have been able to temporarily work around an `unrecognised disk label` (bad partition) error by resetting the partition type with `fdisk`, then copying the data off. This *may* work for you if the issue on the MMC card is with an incomplete file index.

Here's how:

0. Insert the card into the reader
1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
2. List the available devices:

   ```
   sudo fdisk --list
   ```

   This will give you a long list and something that looks like this:

   ```
   Device          Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
   /dev/mmcblk0p1   2048 62332927 62330880 29.7G unknown
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** The example above is from a card of my own. Yours will likely be different.</sup>
3. Have `fdisk` use the device:

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0p1
   ```
4. Press <kbd>T</kbd> to change the type of the partition. If you have multiple (which is unlikely for an SD card), then you will be asked which one to modify.

   <sup>**Note:** If `fdisk` complains about bad partitions or that no partitions exist, then the rest of the points in this answer are irrelevant.</sup>
5. So long as everything is good up to now, you'll see a message like this:

   ```
   Partition type (type L to list all types):
   ```

   Enter `0b`.

   <sup>**Note:** Many SD cards use FAT32 by default, as this file system can be read by any operating system. FAT32 is `0b`. If your card was formatted as something different, be sure to choose the correct partition type. Pressing <kbd>L</kbd> will offer a complete list.</sup>
6. Press <kbd>P</kbd> to check that the partition is showing as FAT32 (or the correct type)
7. Press <kbd>W</kbd> to write the changes to the device, then <kbd>Q</kbd> to exit `fdisk`

So long as enough of the file index remains intact, you may now be able to access the contents of the SD card.

Comment: the problem was something with the partition table, I was able to my computer to read the card but theres many files missing, do you have any ideas what could help? I tried using ntfs but it's saying the volume is corrupted, also, when the computer boots with the card inserted I get this issue: exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): failed to load upcase table (idx : 0x00000c00, chksum : 0xab57008b, utbl_chksum : 0xe619d30d)                                            I also get another error that says "Can't open blockdev".